# How to execute the unix command "top" from scala REPL?

Tags: scala, unix

From the scala REPL, most of the unix commands work fine. Following are the few which I have tried just now:

1. "ps -ef" #| "grep java" !
2. "df -k" !
3. "ls -al .." !

But, when I try "top" I get the following:

```
scala> "top" !
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
error: initializing curses
res13: Int = 1
```

Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: Erm, I don't believe you're supposed to be able to use bash commands in scala. My implementation certainly doesn't allow it. This isn't a troll, is it?

Comment: You can do everything in Scala. /boosterism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fork the process, it's not connected to a tty.

Try batch mode, `top -b -n 1`.

Alternative syntax:

```
scala> Process("top -b -n 1").run
```

Compare error on Linux:

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "top".!
    top: failed tty get
```

On OS X, they call it "logging mode":

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html

I would guess:

```
scala> "top -l 1".!
```

Comment: In my macbook, I am getting : "invalid option or syntax: -b" followed by a list of allowed options. That means the command top is working, but, may not be the option. :-)

Comment: I'm on Linux. Try man top.  I got a different error message, too. Roll with it, Mr Biswas!

Comment: This is what I am getting for most of the options which I am providing according to the help.                                                   scala> Process("top").run
error: initializing curses
res0:scala.sys.process.Process=scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$SimpleProcess@3b517b79

Comment: @ArnabBiswas I don't have a mac here to try, but see the link.  Have you tried `-l` (ell)?